# Not able to understand the context for "such a reading on the basis of political unity would be inaccurate"

Tags: meaning-in-context, subcontinental-english

I am an English learner. Could you explain this statement, because I am struggling to understand the context:

> Considering that such groups have various definitions of separatism and have significant differences in their approach towards Kashmiri nationalism, such a reading on the basis of political unity would be inaccurate.

That is extracted from an article published on July 14 in [*The Hindu*](http://www.thehindu.com/opinion/editorial/major-political-intent-into-an-iftar-meeting-hosted-by-geelani/article7418022.ece).

The particular phrase I am having trouble with is "such a reading on the basis of political unity would be inaccurate."

Comment: Exactly what part of that are you having trouble with? Also, you might be better off on our sister site, [ell.se] in the future.

Comment: @Kevin - "such a reading on the basis of political unity would be inaccurate."

Comment: Replace "considering that" with "because" and drop "such" from "such a reading."  Does that help?

Comment: The question as it appears at ELL: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/61752/not-able-to-understand-the-context-from-the-sentence

Answer (score 1):

The phrase *such a* means it's referring back to something described earlier in the passage. Specifically, it refers to the topic of the first sentence:

> It will be too easy to read major political intent into an Iftar meeting ...

In this context *read* means *interpret*. So the sentence you quoted starts the explanation of why this interpretation is not appropriate. The rest of the paragraph goes into further detail.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a clear break in a sentence, it is sometimes worth reordering it to make more sense of it.

In this case the sentence has a single comma which allows you to switch the last part of the sentence to the front (changing "such" to "because"), so try reading it as...

"A reading on the basis of political unity would be inaccurate BECAUSE such groups have various definitions of separatism and have significant differences in their approach towards Kashmiri nationalism."

Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: Removing _such_ breaks the link with the earlier sentence that this is referring to. It's needed to indicate that a particular reading ("of political intent") is being discussed, not any reading on the basis of political unity.

Answer (score 0):

(I am not a professional in your field, and thus I will answer based on my own understanding)

The groups involved have different definitions/approaches towards something. Therefore, it makes no sense for them to talk about political unity.

Just like in a debate contest, if the two sides cannot even agree on the definition of the topic, it doesn't make any sense for both sides to start providing evidences to support their own claims..

Comment: It makes no sense to _an outsider_ to assume the groups are politically united. Nothing is mentioned or implied about the groups talking about unity.